# Python: subclassing run method of threading gives an error

Tags: python, multithreading

I encountered weird behavior when subclassing Thread of the threading-module of Python 2.7.3.
Consider the next code, called test.py:

```py
import threading

def target_function(): print 'Everything OK'

class SpecificThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        try:
            if self.__target:
                self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
        finally:
            # Avoid a refcycle if the thread is running a function with
            # an argument that has a member that points to the thread.
            del self.__target, self.__args, self.__kwargs  

def check():
    thread = SpecificThread(target=target_function)
    #thread = threading.Thread(target=target_function)
    thread.run()
    print thread.name, 'is running:', thread.is_alive()
```

This code raises the following error when check() is run:

```
>>> check()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 18, in check
    thread.run()
  File "test.py", line 13, in run
    del self.__target, self.__args, self.__kwargs  
AttributeError: _SpecificThread__target
```

Although, the run() method of SpecificThread is exactly the same as the code in the original threading.py module.
If threading.Thread is used or when SpecificThread does not overwrite the run() method, the script runs flawless. I do not understand why overwriting does not work, considering that the Python documentation states that it is allowed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you've encountered is called [name mangling](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) in Python.

It means that all non-system attributes (attributes like "__attrname__") starting with double underscore are automatically renamed by interpreter as _Classname__attrname). That's a kind of protection mechanizm and such design usually means that you souldn't even touch those fields (they are already handled in a proper way), and usually referred to as "private fields".

So, if you want for some reason to get to those fields, use notation above:

```
self._Thread__target
```

Note, that field starts with `_Thread`, not with `_SpecificThread`, because this attribute was defined in `Thread` class.